# How do I do this in Python? List to function

Tags: python

```
def getStuff(x):
    return 'stuff'+x

def getData(x):
    return 'data'+x


thefunctions = []
thefunctions.append("getStuff")
thefunctions.append("getData")

for i in thefunctions:
   print i('abc')
```

Is this possible? Thank you.

Comment: Just remove those quotes. You're adding some strings to that list, but you want to be adding the functions instead.

Comment: @e.e.coli - Post that as an answer and reap the rep.

Comment: Are you implying that I'm a reapist!?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
thefunctions = [ getStuff, getData ]
for f in thefunctions:
    print f('shazam')
```

Once you've done a `def` statement, you've associated a name with a function. Just use that name to refer to the function.